# Label and buttons attached to a dropdown in Semantic UI React

Tags: semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

How can I have a Label and a Button.Group be attached to a Dropdown in Semantic UI for React?

The attached picture shows what I have currently.  If I try using the `attached` attribute, the label or button group become nested within the dropdown.

[image]

Edit: Following is the Semantic UI React markup I currently have:

```
<Label size='big'>Code</Label>
<Dropdown
  options={options}
  placeholder='Choose a Patch'
  search
  selection
  allowAdditions
  value={value}
/>
<Button.Group>
  <Button icon='save' content='Save' color='green' />
  <Button.Or />
  <Button icon='clone' content='Clone' color='yellow' />
  <Button icon='cogs' />
</Button.Group>
```

Comment: Please show some example or your written code.

Comment: @NitinBisht I've updated the question with the Semantic UI React markup I'm currently using.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work with `semantic-ui-react` v2.0.3.

Here's the markup I used:

```html
<Container className='refreshable-dropdown'>
  <Dropdown className='left attached refreshable-dropdown' multiple select />
  <Button className='refreshable-dropdown' attached='right' icon='refresh' />
</Container>
```

You can see I added a CSS class called `refreshable-dropdown`. I added a "refresh" button next to my dropdowns. Here's the CSS classes I used:

```css
/* This is for "fluid" dropdowns that take the whole width of
 * their container.
 */
.ui.container.refreshable-dropdown {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 100%
}

/* If you want the dropdown "inline" with other content, apply
 * the inline CSS class
 */
.ui.container.refreshable-dropdown.inline {
  display: flex-inline;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.ui.attached.dropdown.refreshable-dropdown {
    border-right: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.ui.attached.button.refreshable-dropdown {
    border: 1px solid #2185d0;  /* Specific to my button color */
    border-right: none;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.ui.attached.button.refreshable-dropdown:hover {
    border-color: #1678c2;  /* Specific to my button color*/
}
```

Note that I left the `select` attribute on the Dropdown. This causes some different HTML to be generated than other markdowns, so this may not be 100% applicable to your situation. But I hope it'll at least give you some inspiration for making this work for you. Oh, and here's the resulting dropdown:

[image]